# How to stack two repeating rows of random height divs without any space

Tags: css, drupal-7

This involves Drupal but is really a css question. I am pulling nodes from the database with varying amounts of content, so each `<article/>` is an unpredictable height. But I need to stack the odds on the left and the evens on the right. Basically I want there to be no space (or rather a bottom margin of 24px) between each row on either side. I've tried several versions of this but no matter how there is always a taller `<article/>` that pushes the other column down.

The current css is...

```css
article {
   margin-bottom: 24px;
   background-color: #f6f6f8;
   width: 49%;
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   vertical-align: top;

   /* for IE7 */
   zoom:1;
   *display:inline;
}

article.odd {
   float: left;
   clear: left;
}

article.even {
   margin-left: 18px;
}
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: sorry... did I say divs I meant articles...

Comment: Please post your HTML code! It's best to complete your question with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Do you want two columns of the same size, or just one column with the articles aligned to the sides? It's very difficult to tell what you're asking without more information

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a two column layout.
You can put odd articles in a container (left column) and even articles in another (right column).
Then you can have them stacked independently without gaps.

**HTML**

```
<div class="column"> <!-- left column: odd articles -->
    <article>...</article>
    ...
    <article>...</article>
</div>
<div class="column"> <!-- right column: even articles -->
    <article>...</article>
    ...
    <article>...</article>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 45%; /* or fixed amount */
    margin-right: 5%; /* or fixed amount */
}
```

[Here's a simple Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BqQF3/)

To achieve that you have to list odd and even articles separately, I don't know how to to do that in Drupal, but that's a thing that has to be feasible in every CMS (and goes beyond the scope of this question).
You can find good starting points in [Drupal Documentation](https://drupal.org/documentation) and in [this article](http://www.advomatic.com/blogs/amanda-luker/flowing-list-view-two-columns) (but there the articles are just split: first half in left column, second half in right column).